# Asynchronous XML parsing with SAX in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, apache-poi, sax, kotlin-coroutines

I have a SAX parser reading an XML file (specifically, a .xlsx file) and returning the content as a list of Row objects: it's roughly like this

```
fun readExcelContent(data: InputStream) {
    val pkg = OPCPackage.open(file)
    val reader = XSSFReader(pkg)
    val sst = reader.sharedStringsTable
    val parser = XMLHelper.newXMLReader()
    val handler = ExcelSheetHandler(sst)
    parser.contentHandler = handler
    val sheet = reader.sheetsData.next()
    val source = InputSource(sheet)
    parser.parse(source)

    return handler.content
}
```

Where `ExcelSheetHandler` is a class that extends `DefaultHandler` and takes care of filling up a list:

```
class ExcelSheetHandler(sst: SharedStringsTable): DefaultHandler() {

    private val content = mutableListOf<Row>()

    @Throws(SAXException::class)
    override fun endElement(uri: String?, localName: String?, name: String) {
        // If it's the end of a content element, add a row to content
    }
}
```

It's basically a slight modification of the event model example in the [Apache POI howto](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api).

I was wondering if there was a way to have `readExcelContent` return an asynchronous object, such as a flow, and emit the rows to its client as soon as they are read rather than having to wait for the whole file to be processed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer `kotlinx.coroutines.Channel` over `kotlinx.coroutines.Flow` for this use case since this is a hot stream of data triggered by the `parse()` method. Here's what [Kotlin Language Guide](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/flow.html#flows) states.

> Flows are cold streams similar to sequences — the code inside a flow
>   builder does not run until the flow is collected

Here's a quick implementation that you can try.

```
class ExcelSheetHandler : DefaultHandler() {

    private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)
    private val rows = Channel<Row>()

    override fun endDocument() {
        // To avoid suspending forever!
        rows.close()
    }

    @Throws(SAXException::class)
    override fun endElement(uri: String?, localName: String?, name: String) {
        readRow(uri, localName, name)
    }

    private fun readRow(uri: String?, localName: String?, name: String) = runBlocking {
        // If it's the end of a content element, add a row to content
        rows.send(row)
    }

    // Client code - if it needs to be somewhere else
    // you can expose a reference to Channel object
    private fun processRows() = scope.launch {
        for(row in rows) {
            // Do something
            println(row)
        }
    }
}
```